# Covariant and contravariant functor

Tags: category-theory

There is a question on proving that a contravariant functor from category $C$ to category $D$ is the covariant functor from the opposite category of $C$ to $D$ and also a covariant functor from $C$ to the opposite category of $D$
(I have shown that this functor maps objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms...but I am not able to show how identity and composition will be preserved in this)..Please explain how to prove these two properties.

Comment: Presumably you already tried following the relevant definitions (of opposite category and of contravariant functor) to write out carefully the information you're given and the information that you want to deduce. As far as I can see, the given information and the desired information are identical. So it would be useful if you tell us exactly where you encountered a problem, for example in the proof that composition is preserved.

Comment: I did mention that..I have been stuck in proving that identity and composition are preserved

Comment: I saw that, but, as I said, I can't imagine what the difficulties could have been, for either the identities or composition. As far as I can see, once you write out the given information and write out what you need to prove, and then apply the relevant definitions, there's nothing left to do.

Answer (score 2):

As Andreas said, this is a matter of carefully checking equivalence of definitions, so for the sake of completeness and to avoid ambiguities I will first give the definition of a (covariant) functor and then that of a contravariant functor to then show partially that the definitions in question coincide; I say partially because to show equivalence of definitions is an "if and only if proof", but giving one half of it should be enough for you to see how to do the other bit, as the strategy is exactly analogous.

> **Definition:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be categories. A *(covariant) functor* $F$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ is a mapping such that:
>
> - $F$ assigns to every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ an object $F(X)$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

- $F$ assigns to every morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ a morphism $F(f):F(X) \rightarrow F(Y)$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

> Moreover, $F$ satisfies the *functoriality axioms:*
>
> 1. $F(id_{X})= id_{F(X)}$ for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$.
> 2. $F(g \circ f) = F(g) \circ F(f)$ for all morphisms $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

$\ $

> **Definition:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be categories. A *contravariant functor* $F$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ is a mapping such that:
>
> - $F$ assigns to every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ an object $F(X)$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

- $F$ assigns to every morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ a morphism $F(f):F(Y) \rightarrow F(X)$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

> Moreover, $F$ satisfies the *functoriality axioms:*
>
> 1. $F(id_{X})= id_{F(X)}$ for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$.
> 2. $F(g \circ f) = F(f) \circ F(g)$ for all morphisms $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

---

> **Claim:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be categories. A contravariant functor $F$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ is a (covariant) functor $F'$ from $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ to $\mathcal{D}$.

**Proof of Claim:** Let $F$ be a contravariant functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. Note that $F$ takes objects to objects and identity morphisms to identity morphisms by definition, so after setting $F'(X) = F(X)$ and $F'(id_{X}) = F(id_{X})$ for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ there are just two remaining things to do/check.

- $\underline{\textit{F' takes morphisms to morphisms:}}$ Let $f: Y \rightarrow X$ be an arrow in $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$. Then there is an arrow $f^{\text{op}}: X \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and since $F$ is a contravariant functor by assumption, $F(f^{\text{op}}): F(Y) \rightarrow F(X)$ is an arrow in $\mathcal{D}$, so defining $F'(f)$ to be $F(f^{\text{op}}) : F(Y) \rightarrow F(X)$ gives a mapping which assigns to every arrow $f: Y \rightarrow X$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ an arrow $F'(Y) \rightarrow F'(X)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ (note that $F'(Y) = F(Y)$ and $F'(X) = F(X)$ by the above).
- $\underline{\textit{F' respects the second functoriality axiom:}}$ Let $f: Y \rightarrow X$ and $g: Z \rightarrow Y$ be two arrows in $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$, so that $f^{\text{op}}: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g^{\text{op}}: Y \rightarrow Z$ are arrows in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $f\circ g: Z \rightarrow X$ is an arrow in $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$  and $(f\circ g)^{\text{op}}: X \rightarrow Z$ is an arrow in $\mathcal{C}$, so:

\begin{align}
F'(f \circ g) & = F((f\circ g)^{\text{op}}) \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ &\text{ by definition of } F' \\
&= F(g^{\text{op}}\circ f^{\text{op}}) \  &\text{ since } (f\circ g)^{\text{op}} = g^{\text{op}}\circ f^{\text{op}}\\
&= F(f^{\text{op}})\circ F(g^{\text{op}}) \ &\text{ since }F\text{ is a contravariant functor}\\
&= F'(f)\circ F'(g) \ &\text{by definition of }F'
\end{align}

Comment: When do we say that two functors F and F' between categories are same? .When F(X)=F'(X) for all objects X?

Comment: @bhavna Remember what a functor is: a *mapping*. When do we say that two functions are the same? When they take the same values for all elements in their domain. However, functors also map morphisms to morphisms, so not only they have to agree on objects but also on arrows to be the same.

Comment: @bhavna But note that I'm NOT saying that $F=F'$ here! They cannot be equal since they their domain/codomain categories are different; what I'm proving in the claim is that any functor $F$ *can be regarded as* a functor $F'$, and to show full equivalence of definitions you can show that any functor $F'$ can be regarded as a functor $F$. In short, $F$ and $F'$ are not *equal* but *naturally isomorphic*.

Comment: You constructed F' with the help of F.What do you mean by regarding F' as F?

Comment: @bhavna I mean that given $F'$ one can construct $F$. Moreover, this construction is  mutually inverse with constructing $F'$ from $F$.

Comment: But that isn't something we were supposed to prove..Is it?

Comment: @bhavna What you want to show is that any $F$ can be thought of as $F'$, and that just means that the definitions of $F$ and $F'$ are equivalent; showing equivalence of definitions, as I said in my answer, is an "if and only if proof", and in my answer I have just given one direction (that of starting from $F$ we get $F'$), since the other is similar.

Comment: @bhavna When you are asked to show that any contravariant functor $F$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ is a covariant functor from $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ you are asked to verify equivalence of definitions. This wording of *can be thought of/regarded as* is common, see for example the third paragraph under section 2 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/contravariant+functor.

Comment: F can be thought of as F'?..We just constructed F' with help of F?How can they be regaded as same?

Comment: @Rick It is a very helpful answer, thank you

Comment: @Rick, in order to have natural isomorphism between 2 functors, shouldn't both the functors lie in the same functor category? In this case, the domain category and the target category are not the same for the 2 functors. So, what do you precisely mean by them to be naturally isomorphic?